# How to disable external site css on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I am using IFrame to load an external site on my site , In my research i found that due to cross domain issue browsers will not let you disable the css/js of an external site.

Do we have any other options for to achieve this?

Comment: Don't load an external site at all then! There's a huge security reason why IFrame modification is disallowed. You wouldn't want a site to load your bank's website in an IFrame, and they modify it and/or capture data from that frame, do you?

Comment: [Use server-side code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to download just the HTML of the remote site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the page of another domain in an iframe. Browsers don't allow it.